# Java Parse Json response string

Tags: java, json

```
{
    "count": 61,
    "next": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Alderaan",
            "rotation_period": "24",
        },
        {
            "name": "Yavin IV",
            "rotation_period": "24",
        },

    ]
}
```

How I can convert to Array? Whe JsonObject Requires Map?

```
    String responseString=content.toString();
    System.out.println(responseString);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
```

Error:
JSONObject request map

Comment: Which JSON library are you using? In other words from which package you import `JSONObject`? OR what you see when you execute `System.out.println(JSONObject.class.getName());`?

Comment: What you want to do is called deserialization. You probably want to use `ObjectMapper`. It's pretty easy to use. See [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) for some examples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: Library org.json.simple.JSONObject

Comment: `org.json.simple.JSONObject` doesn't have constructor which accepts String, `org.json.JSONObject` does but that is different library.

Comment: How I can install it? From Marvel?

Comment: How did you "install" `org.json.simple`? If your project is configured to use Maven or Gradle then just add proper dependency. If not you can always add JAR file manually to your project, you can download JAR from https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java (scroll down to see more info beside project structure).